# How do I use document.write() to write an event unless it is already written?

Tags: javascript, arrays, document.write, control-flow

I've created an array containing: [Event Location, Date, Event Name].
I am using a forEach loop to iterate through each event and using document.write to print out the details. That part is going well.

However, I don't want to print out the event's title *every* time. I want to print out the title only once and then the details beneath it. To clarify I want it to visually look something like this:

**Meet and Greet**

- Boston November
- New York December
- Concord May
- Cincinnati October

**Drink Coffee**

- Texas August
- San Antonio February

**Dance With Me**

- Anchorage June

[Here](http://codepen.io/toymechqm/pen/OyrWxB) is what it visually looks like. If you look at the code pen all it is doing is writing the value of title right now. How can I overwrite the value of the event's title if it is unique and print out that title only **once**?
[Here](https://repl.it/BZ9z/6) is my personal attempt at doing it using an if loop and reassigning the value of title.

```
<script>
    var events = 
      [ 
        ["New York",  "November 5-8, 2015",   "Meet and Greet"],
        ["Detroit",   "November 5-8, 2015",   "Meet and Greet"],
        ["Boston",    "April 5-8, 2015",    "Meet and Greet"],
        ["Boston",    "November 5-8, 2015",   "Drink Coffee"],
        ["Boston",    "July 5-8, 2015",     "Drink Coffee"],
        ["Phoenix",   "December 5-8, 2015",   "Drink Coffee"],
        ["Phoenix",   "July 5-8, 2015",     "Dance With Me"],
        ["Phoenix",   "April 5-8, 2015",    "Dance With Me"],
        ["Boston",    "December 5-8, 2015",   "Dance With Me"],
        ["Boston",    "December 5-8, 2015",   "Dance With Me"],
        ["Boston",    "October 5-8, 2015",  "Dance With Me"],
        ["Boston",    "September 5-8, 2015",  "Kiss Me... I'm Irish"],
        ["Orlando",   "May 5-8, 2015",    "Kiss Me... I'm Irish"],
        ["Orlando",   "August 5-8, 2015",   "Kiss Me... I'm Irish"],
        ["Orlando",   "February 5-8, 2015",   "Potty Training"],
        ["Boston",    "June 5-8, 2015",     "Potty Training"],
        ["Boston",    "May 5-8, 2015",    "Potty Training"],
        ["Boston",    "February 5-8, 2015",   "I Married an Axe Murderer"],
        ["Boston",    "September 5-8, 2015",  "Meet The Authors"],
        ["San Antonio", "August 5-8, 2015",   "Meet The Authors"],
        ["San Antonio", "January 5-8, 2015",  "Sponsorship"],
        ["San Antonio", "October 5-8, 2015",  "Sponsorship", ],
        ["Boston",    "January 5-8, 2015",  "Lose Weight... FAST"],
        ["Boston",    "October 5-8, 2015",  "Lose Weight... FAST"],
        ["Boston",    "August 5-8, 2015",   "Getting Started"]
      ];

    events.forEach(function(entry) {
      var month  = entry[1].split(' ');
      var calNum = entry[1].split(' ')[1].charAt(0);
      var title = "Sweeps Events";
      document.write(
        title
      + "<div class='panel panel-default event'>"
      +     "<div class='row month-icon'>"
      +       "<div class='col-md-1 text-center'>"
      +         month[0]
      +       "<br>"
      +         "<span class='fa-stack fa-2x'>"
      +         "<i class='fa fa-calendar-o fa-stack-2x'></i>"
      +         "<strong class='fa-stack-1x calendar-text'>"+calNum+"</strong>"
      +       "</span>"
      +       "</div>"
      +       "<div class='col-md-6'>"
      +       "<h3 class='event-headers'>"
      +           entry[1]
      +       "<h3>"
      +       "<h3 class='event-headers'>"
      +         entry[0]
      +       "</h3>" 
      +       "</div>"
      +       "<div class='col-md-5 text-right'>"
      +         "<a class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success' href='#''><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-2x'></i><strong>Register Now</strong></a>"
      +       "</div>"
      +     "</div>"
      + "</div>"
      );
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Okay Thanks, but If I do, will that solve the issue I am having. meaning will I still be able to iterate through the events and not copying the html 25 times, and will I be able to post the title in the way I am trying to do?

Comment: I would restructure the data.  Some thing like events = [{title : "Meet and greet", place: "New Your", time: "November 5-8, 2015"}, { --- repeat ---}].  That way you can just insert outline using DOM methods.  Unless of course you were handed the data as is.

Answer (score 1):

Document.write even warns you in the specs that it isn't 100% reliable. Like Oriol said, try to use a DOM method like document.getElementById();

Answer (score 1):

José,

I just made that generator, so it may not be 100% yet, because I'm seeing a bug I didn't realize before.

Anyway that you loop through the events though, this should be the absolute easiest way to solve this particular question:

```
 title = lastTitle != data[2]? lastTitle = data[2]  : "";
```

Another way of saying that is this:

```
if (lastTitle != data[2]) {
    title = data[2];
    lastTitle = data[2];
} else {
    title = "";
}
```

Just show the title only if it differ's from the last title. That's why I say if your data is set up sequentially like that, then you're in good shape. Otherwise, it would get complicated and it would be better off restructuring the data.

`Array.foreach` and `document.write` are still not good ideas, so I'd recommend something like this as a solution for now:

```
var lastTitle;

while
(   entry = events.shift()
)   {
        var month  = entry[1].split(' ');
        var calNum = entry[1].split(' ')[1].charAt(0);
        var title = lastTitle!=data[2]? lastTitle=data[2]: "";
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
        .innerHTML=(
        title
          + "<div class='panel panel-default event'>"
          +     "<div class='row month-icon'>"
          +       "<div class='col-md-1 text-center'>"
          +         month[0]
          +       "<br>"
          +         "<span class='fa-stack fa-2x'>"
          +         "<i class='fa fa-calendar-o fa-stack-2x'></i>"
          +         "<strong class='fa-stack-1x calendar-text'>"+calNum+"</strong>"
          +       "</span>"
          +       "</div>"
          +       "<div class='col-md-6'>"
          +       "<h3 class='event-headers'>"
          +           entry[1]
          +       "<h3>"
          +       "<h3 class='event-headers'>"
          +         entry[0]
          +       "</h3>" 
          +       "</div>"
          +       "<div class='col-md-5 text-right'>"
          +         "<a class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success' href='#''><i class='fa fa-pencil fa-2x'></i><strong>Register Now</strong></a>"
          +       "</div>"
          +     "</div>"
          + "</div>"
          );
    }
;
```

For the loop, you might rather do something like:

```
for
(   var event, i=0
;   event=events[i++];
)   {
        //
    }
```

or

```
var
    event
,   i = 0
;

while
(   event = events[i++]
)
    {
        //
    }
```

or

```
for (var each in events)
(   function as (event)
    {
        //
    }
)   (events[each]);
```

Sorry I couldn't get the generator completely working in time. I'd avise against using it until I can get it fixed! This should hold you over for your purposes, though!